# Issue with if-else condition in jqgrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I have issue with `if else` condition in `jqgrid` column.

I am passing `true` in the `if` condition (i.e `editaccess == true`), but sometimes it is going into `if` and sometime it going into `else`.

**JS:**

```
{ 
    name: 'edit',
    index: 'edit', 
    width: '50px', 
    sortable: false, 
    sortable: false, 
    align: 'center', 
    formatter: function (cell, options, obj) { 
         if (editaccess) {
             return "<img src=" + editImage + " title=\"Edit\"  alt=\"Edit\" class=\"toolTip\" onclick=\"something();\" />";
         }
          else {
             return "";
         }
    }
```

Note: Bundling is enabled. Also checked fiddler for response and it is giving true for the condition when it is going into else.

Comment: More information please

Comment: put a console log and check the value of `editaccess`. If it is still correct, check if img src is not undefined `editaccess`

Comment: @Vijay  value for editaccess is true that i mentioned i checked in fiddler.
and also not the issue src because if i put some text in else condition it is shown

Comment: in that case the variable is not setting properly. please check again in your code whether you are updating it or not.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a curly bracket from the end of your code block.

Revised code:

```
{ 
    name: 'edit', index: 'edit', width: '50px', sortable: false, sortable: false, align: 'center', formatter: function (cell, options, obj) { 
    if (editaccess) {
        return "<img src=" + editImage + " title=\"Edit\"  alt=\"Edit\"     class=\"toolTip\" onclick=\"something();\" />";
        }
        else {
            return "";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: HI thanks,
i just copy pasted the code so could have missed a curly bracket.

but Issue is sometime it goes into if and sometimes else

Comment: Ok could you post the code for where editaccess is being set? Or make a fiddle with it?

Comment: it is set from ajax call and don't think fiddle will help as i am not able to reproduce while debuging...

just getting this when hosted.